# CodeIgniter Daylight Savings

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm working on a booking system with a client and bookings were made during daylight savings... now that daylight savings isn't in effect, the bookings made are all showing the wrong times. Example: Room booked between 3-4pm was showing as 2-3pm.

In my `application/config/config.php` file I have `$config['default_timezone'] = 'Europe/London';` but this doesn't seem to help.

Any pointers?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you stored the date that the rooms were booked, which you must have, you could check if they were booked during daylight savings time using 
    `date('I', strtotime($date))`
which will return a 1 if $date is in daylight savings time and 0 if not. Then call it again with time() to see if it is currently daylight savings time. Subtract/add an hour accordingly.